# Monitoring file locks, locked using flock

Tags: files, lock, inotify

I would like to get a list of pid's which hold shared lock on `/tmp/file`. Is this possible using simple command line tools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- From `man lsof`:

  FD         is the File Descriptor number of the file or:

                FD is followed by one of these characters, describing the mode under which the file is open:

  ```
            The mode character is followed by one of these lock characters, describing the type of lock applied to the file:

                 R for a read lock on the entire file;
                 W for a write lock on the entire file;
                 space if there is no lock.
  ```

So `R` in `3uR` mean that read/shared lock is issued by `613` PID.

```
#lsof /tmp/file
COMMAND PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
perl    613 turkish    3uR  REG    8,2        0 1306357 /tmp/file
```

---

- Reading directly from `/proc/locks` is faster than `lsof`,

  ```
  perl -F'[:\s]+' -wlanE'
    BEGIN { $inode = (stat(pop))[1]; @ARGV = "/proc/locks" }
    say "pid:$F[4] [$_]" if $F[7] == $inode
  ' /tmp/file
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`fuser /tmp/file` will list all processes which have the file open, including those that have a lock on it.

Comment: Yes, and `lsof` is also aware of that but `flock` can refuse locking, or pid could wait for lock after file opening.

Comment: No, it will not necessary list all processes, only processes on the same System. This can break for network storage.